# How to strip nulls from jsonb field on EF Core Npgsql (PostgreSQL)

Tags: entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm using EF Core 6 (6.0.11) with [Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg) (6.0.7).

I have an entity with a property mapped to a JSON field on the table of a postgres database.

```cs
    public class Book
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
        public PhysicalProperties PhysicalProperties { get; set; }
    }

    public class PhysicalProperties
    {
        public int? Weight { get; set; }
        public int? Width { get; set; }
        public int? Depth { get; set; }
        public int? Height { get; set; }
        public int? Pages { get; set; }
        public bool? HardCover { get; set; }

    }
```

Notice that every property on "PhysicalProperties" is nullable.
When I save a record on the database, the json saved looks like this:

`{Weight: null, Width: null, Depth: null, Height: null, Pages: 223, HardCover: false}`

I would like to not save on the database the null properties.

`{Pages: 223, HardCover: false}`

If I edit manually the JSON on the database, Npgsql parses correctly the values and gives me the object correctly populated. But after saving it again, it'll write all the properties again.

Is it possible to strip the null valued properties from the JSON and keep the typed property?

I found [this](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1107#issuecomment-945126627) workaround, but I don't know how to implement it on my WebAPI. I tried to add the relevant code to the OnConfiguring method of my Context, and to the ConfigureService on my Startup class. Without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=data-annotations%2Cpoco), it uses Text.Json to serialize objects. It means that you can **try to use** `[JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]` for each of the properties you have. In your case, it might look like this:

```cs
    public class Book
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
        public PhysicalProperties PhysicalProperties { get; set; }
    }

    public class PhysicalProperties
    {
        [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
        public int? Weight { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
        public int? Width { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
        public int? Depth { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
        public int? Height { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
        public int? Pages { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
        public bool? HardCover { get; set; }

    }
```

More detail about annotation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-7-0)